# multiple JAXB serializations for one class?

Tags: jboss, mapping, jaxb, resteasy, jboss6.x

i have a Class A that is used as a result for a JAX-RS method. I want to marshal A into xml in two different ways.

Is there a way to give resteasy two different mappings to use on my class?

Greetings,
Laures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the **[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)** lead and a member of the JAXB 2 ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

You could use MOXy for this.  Check out my blog post where I map the same object model to two different weather services (Google and Yahoo) by leveraging annotations for one mapping and MOXy's XML metadata for the second mapping:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

Below is an example of using MOXy's XML metadata in a JAX-RS environment:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/moxys-xml-metadata-in-jax-rs-service.html

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for [JAXB RI](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/ANX/JAXB+User+Guide).
The same idea: define JAXB annotations in XML resources.